# Failed to install optbinning in python: ERROR: Could not build wheels for scs, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, module, package

I've tried to install optbinning package in python using Jupyter Notebook, but got an error.

```
!pip install optbinning



 ERROR: Could not build wheels for scs, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the CVXPY dependency. On Windows, you might need Microsoft Build Tools and Cython. On Linux, Mac you should not encounter any issue if a C++ compiler is installed.